# Why is WolframScript necessary?

Tags: packages

Hi  I have erased (for lack of space) WolframScript (without being sure of why it is needed), and now I get lots of error warnings like

Set::wrsym: Symbol m is Protected.

Is there a way to supress for good these warnings, or to reinstall the WolframScript

Comment: You deleted it for space?  As in you needed to save 8MB of space so you deleted a file from the installation directory that you didn't know the purpose of?

Comment: It was one of the biggest mistakes of my life :)  Now I guess I need  to reinstall, or to stop using names of one letter , which has become impossible

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, whether it's possible to just install `wolframscript`, or what part of the system was using it before.  I also don't know what code is trying to set a value to `m` and why it would be protected

Comment: Thanks:) What tricked me is it appeared on the list of programs separately from WolframMathematica, so I assumed wrongly it is less necessary :)   About m, it is in fact all one word symbols which become unusable

Comment: I have the `wolframscript.exe` file in two locations. In the main install directory as well as in the SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries. I don't know if these are just links or not, but see if you can make a copy to the other location. As a last step, I would install it elsewhere (on another computer or virtual machine) and bring back just the file(s) I deleted and see if it could work. The last choice would be re-installation.

Comment: I believe it is not necessary. It is in fact installed separately on macOS. However, it takes up no appreciable amount of space and it is completely pointless to delete it for space-saving reasons.

Comment: Thanks :) Luckily, it is packaged separately from the rest, so I was able to reinstall it in 2 seconds, without reinstalling the rest :)